# Is there a format in Python where I can represent any arbitrary range that I can pass to index another array?

Tags: python, arrays, range

Right now I'm using a tuple with start and end index:

```
ind_range = (34,98)
```

but what I want is:

```
ind_range = (34:98)
```

so I can pass this directly to the array:

```
array[ind_range]
```

Edit:

Original question answered: use `range()`

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is index another array with a list of index ranges.

```
ind_ranges=[range(5,9), range(13,19)]
```

```
array[ind_ranges]
```

```
output: [[values from range1],[values from range2]]
```

When I do this I get the error:

> IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean)
>   type

**Final Edit:**

Correct answer: use a `slice` object in combination with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object.

```
s = slice(34, 98)
```

Now you can just use

```
array[s]
```

Use a list comprehension if you want to use multiple slices:

```
slices= [slice(34, 98), slice(34, 98), slice(34, 98)]
values = [array[s] for s in slices]
```

Comment: the list comprehension part is exactly what I needed, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Literally just `array[range(34, 98)]`.

Since you're all struggling, here's a step by step tutorial:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

print(arr[range(2, 4)])
```

`Out[1]: [3 4]`

Comment: ok 2nd question. when I try to index with a list of ranges, I get this issue: `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Comment: This answer isn't correct i didn't downvote but please update

Comment: numpy arrays and lists are two different things

Comment: OP said multiple times that he is working with an array, and not a list.

Comment: FYI, Python has [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) without numpy, which don't behave much like numpy's [ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/arrays.ndarray.html).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - Nicolas' solution returns `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not range` for me in python 3

```
>>> arr = [i for i in range(15)]
>>> start, end = 8, 12
>>> arr[start:end]
[8, 9, 10, 11]
```